# ES6 lexical scoping issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The below example works fine and Lexical scoping is available in inner scope.

```
var fn =function(){

  this.no = 0;

  this.addNo = () => {

      setTimeout( ()=> {
        // ES6 lexical scope is available 
        this.no =++this.no;
        console.log(this.no);
      }, 2000);

  }

}

var f1 = new fn();
f1.addNo();
f1.addNo();
```

Where as the below example does not work.

```
var fn =() =>{

  this.no = 0;

  this.addNo = () => {

      setTimeout( ()=> {
        // ES6 lexical scope is not available 
        this.no =++this.no;
        console.log(this.no);
      }, 2000);

  }

}

var f1 = new fn();
f1.addNo();
f1.addNo();
```

Error

**"TypeError: Cannot set property 'no' of undefined**

Comment: "Scoping" has nothing to do with the issue here, since you've declared only that outer function as a variable of any sort. The problem is with how `this` is bound for arrow functions vs. regular functions.

Comment: I understand that the below code works if I give a named function traditional way. But why could not get it.

Comment: arrow functions do not have constructors; you cannot use the new keyword to instantiate them.

Comment: I wonder how you tested your code because as @ndugger correctly said you cannot use `new` with arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

es5 translate add function like this:

```
"use strict";
```

var fn = function fn() {

```
undefined.no = 0;

undefined.addNo = function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
        // ES6 lexical scope is not available
        undefined.no = ++undefined.no;
        console.log(undefined.no);
    }, 2000);
};
```

};
and es6 translate code like that so you can see the different.

```
var _this = this;
```

var fn = () => {

```
_this.no = 0;

_this.addNo = () => {

    setTimeout(() => {
        // ES6 lexical scope is not available
        _this.no = ++_this.no;
        console.log(_this.no);
    }, 2000);
};
```

};

because function with no default scope,then in es5 this is undefined.in es6 complier use this in function bind to the top scope.